# Nexmo not sending SMS to US Number, but able to send to Indian Number

Tags: sms, vonage

Curl for posting message to US number:

```
curl -X POST "https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json"   -d "from=1XXXXXXXXXX"   -d "text=A text message set using the Nexmo SMS API"   -d "to=1XXXXXXXXXX"   -d "api_key=my_api_key"   -d "api_secret=my_api_secret"
```

Response:

```
{
    "message-count": "1",
    "messages": [{
        "to": "1XXXXXXXXXX",
        "status": "15",
        "error-text": "Illegal Sender Address - rejected",
        "network": "XXXXXX"
    }]
}
```

---

Curl for posting message to Indian number:

```
curl -X POST "https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json"   -d "from=1XXXXXXXXXX"   -d "text=A text message set using the Nexmo SMS API"   -d "to=91XXXXXXXXXX"   -d "api_key=my_api_key"   -d "api_secret=my_api_secret"
```

Response:

```
{
    "message-count": "1",
    "messages": [{
        "to": "91XXXXXXXXXX",
        "message-id": "0F000XXXXF05XXX6",
        "status": "0",
        "remaining-balance": "48.96XXXXXX",
        "message-price": "0.00800000",
        "network": "XXXXX"
    }]
}
```

This was working fine for both US and Indian Number, but recently it is giving me `Illegal Sender Address - rejected` error.

Has nexmo changed anything?

Comment: [In the “from” field you need to specify your ***pre-approved*** US virtual number in international format e.g. 13036320365 (available in the Numbers tab) . Otherwise your message will get rejected with reject code 15 Illegal Sender Address - rejected.](https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/articles/204017023-USA-SMS-Features-Restrictions)

Comment: I am using sender number in international format. This was working in February 2019 (It was the last time I checked). Was this some recent change?

Comment: If the number is pre-approved, there should have been no change and you're probably better off contacting support. If it's not, I'm not sure if there have been any recent changes for the US specifically.

Comment: Thanks @JoachimIsaksson, it worked. I purchased pre-approved number from Nexmo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please see this page for restrictions on USA SMS features: 
https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/articles/204017023-USA-SMS-Features-Restrictions

Specifically:

"All SMS sent to the US must originate from either a U.S. pre-approved long number or short code that is associated with your Nexmo account. Alpha sender IDs are not supported."